# Chartjs pie chart not showing from dynamic data

Tags: jquery, charts, chart.js

I have a data from database and I want to display it in a pie chart but the problem is that the pie chart is now showing.

```
var data = [];
        $.each(res, function(index, client){

            data.push({

                value : client.total_amount,
                color : "#F7464A",
                highlight : "#FF5A5E",
                label : client['client'].name

            });
        })
console.log(data)
var ctx = $("#client-stats").get(0).getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding parseFloat will solved the problem.

```
    data.push({

               value : parseFloat(client.total_amount),
               color : "#F7464A",
               highlight : "#FF5A5E",
               label : client['client'].name

   });
```